# Extract number from a string followed by "I-"

Tags: c#, string, extract

In C#, I assigned this last line from a log file to string "str"
I want to extract the numbers following "I-" and store it in a data type for use it later in the program.  In the example below I need to get 667466.
Please help how to do this?

```
string str = "2017-01-16 11:10:37.151 +11:00 [Information] OutboundMessageFile:MessageFields: [KeyValuePair`2 { Key: \"ConfirmationCode\", Value: \"I-667466\" }], MessageAttachments: \"\", MessageConfig: \"\", MachineName: \"MARYDEV234\" }"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to find this data.

```
var regex = new Regex("Value: \"I-(\\d+)\"");
var match = regex.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
    var data = match.Groups[1].Value;
    // Store data for next use
}
```

Comment: Thanks Uladzimir, but when i used the above code, "{Value: "I-667466"}" is stored in "match" and then var data is null .... 667466 is not stored in var data.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like Uladzimir's regex solution, but here's an alternative:

```
string str = "2017-01-16 11:10:37.151 +11:00 [Information] OutboundMessageFile:MessageFields: [KeyValuePair`2 { Key: \"ConfirmationCode\", Value: \"I-667466\" }], MessageAttachments: \"\", MessageConfig: \"\", MachineName: \"MARYDEV234\" }";
int index = str.IndexOf("I-");
index += 2; //Skip the "I-"
string output = "";
for(int i = index; true; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == '"')
        break;
    output += str[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This only works on strings specifically formatted like you have though, the regex solution is more generalizable.  You can upgrade this version to make `output` a StringBuilder instead of a string too.